# Python out-of-order range?

Tags: python, loops, range

Instead of doing

```
for i in range(begin, end):
```

I want to do something like

```
for i in begin+1, begin+2, begin, begin+3 through end:
```

If this makes sense at all?

Comment: What do you mean? Is there a specific pattern?

Comment: no pattern, just the way I have it outlined above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in [begin+1, begin+2, begin] + range(begin+3, end):
```

Comment: Not random -- the specific order outlined in the OP

Comment: @JohnSmith, ok, something like this then?

Comment: John, can you explain yourself better? You've got a few people asking for clarification, so merely repeating that you meant what you said initially isn't sufficient. Please give us a sample sequence so we can help you.

Comment: @Jimothy The pattern is explicitly stated in the OP

Comment: @gnibbler Is there a way to also ensure the begin+1, begin+2, begin+3 do not go past "end" as well?

Comment: John, I'm not the only one having trouble understanding your problem. But since all you're doing is repeating yet again "that pattern is in the OP," I guess you're not really interested in getting help.

Comment: @Jimothy What is hard to understand about begin+1, begin+2, begin, begin+3 to end? I am not trying to be rude but I literally can't get any more explicit than that and don't see how it could possibly be misinterpreted

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I think this is a job for `itertools.chain`.

```
from itertools import chain
def disorderedrange(begin, end):
    return chain((begin+1, begin+2, begin, begin+3), range(begin+4, end))

for i in disorderedrange(1, 100):
    # loop content goes here.
```

This is better than gnibbler's solution if the range is large (as this avoids creating a temporary list holding the entire range.).